# C#: Custom control is resizing on its own

Tags: c#, winforms, controls

I have a custom control built of other controls that is being loaded in two different places. On one it appears the way it does in the designer, as expected, on the other it is being resized smaller without being instructed to do so. Even when I explicitly adjust the size in code the control appears to get bigger, but the controls within are still smaller than they should be. What could causing this to happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any differences in the font size between the custom controls' containers (form, panel, etc.)?

See if setting your control's [AutoScaleMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.containercontrol.autoscalemode.aspx) to `Dpi` helps.